# drawing html elements in fixed rows/columns positions

Tags: html

I have been asked to draw html elements (text, checkboxes, text fields) in fixed positions (row, column).
As example here is how the elements should be positioned.

```
row | column | element<br>
1   | 1      | Title1<br>
1   | 14     | Text field (size = 20)<br>
1   | 40     | Tile2<br>
1   | 50     | Text field (size = 10)<br>
2   |...<br>
```

I tried the solution with tables as follows

```
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="13">Title1</td><td colspan="26">Text field
```

... But this appeared to be a bad solution because of the empty space between cells. The empty space is generated by cells in other rows (containing images for example)
The 2nd solution with one td and a `<pre>` tag (setting the text field border to 0 lead to fields not 100% vertically aligned

How is it possible to display such data?

---

An example of what I am doing is:

```
01|01|User                 :
01|25|Text field size = 10
03|01|Name 1               :
03|25|Text field size = 30
04|01|Name 2               :
04|25|Text field size = 30
04|25|Text field size = 30
05|01|Aubreviation         :
05|25|Text field size = 05
06|01|User group           :
06|25|Text field size = 10
06|37|Text field size = 44
07|01|Telephone            :
07|25|Text field size = 20
08|01|E-mail               :
08|25|Text field size = 50
09|01|Company allocation   :
09|25|Text field size = 9
10|01|Name of printer      :
10|25|Text field size = 10
10|37|Message
11|01|Language code        :
11|25|Text field size = 2
13|01|Message delete cycle :
13|25|Text field size = 9
13|28|Days
15|01|SBM mess.delete cyc. :
15|25|Text field size = 9
15|28|Days
```

The output should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ1f9.gif
The fields should be perfectly aligned in the HTML output as in the image below.

Comment: Your ascii-art table doesn't show any requirement for `colspan`. Do you want it to look *exactly* like that table, or differently? Can you post your actual mark-up and, ideally, an image to show what you want it to look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using [CSS absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) instead of tables to layout your page.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be misunderstanding here, as in the example, the word “column” apparently relates to a character position on a line. Presumably, the rendering is supposed to use equal width for all characters, i.e. use a monospace font. A column in this sense is very different from a table column (which is what colspan relates to).

The normal way in HTML would use just

```
<tr> <td><label for="a1">Title1</label></td> <td><input name="a1" id="a1"  size="20"></td>
     <td><label for="a2">Title1</label></td> <td><input name="a2" id="a2"  size="10"></td> </tr>
```

If needed, the widths of columns (in the HTML sense) would be set in CSS, or maybe using width attributes in  tags. There is, however, no way to specify the width in characters (there’s a proposed unit for that in CSS3 drafts, but it hasn’t been implemented). I’d suggest that you ask for clarification on this: should the layout really reflect typewriter-style formatting that implies monospace characters, or is it OK that each column just occupies its natural width (as wide as needed).

Answer (score 0):

The solution with label cannot be used in this context because:
there exist several empty spaces betwwen labels wich have to be respected.
As example here are the two first entries of a dialog.

```
01|01|Part
01|14|:
02|01|Change       :
```

In line 1 the ':' should be at position : if it is correctly displayed it should be perfectly aligned with the ':' at the end of Change but this is not the case.
I even tried the solution with `<pre>` and fill the empty spaces with spaces (' ') and here I got another problem. If a text field (size=1) is vertically aligned with a label then the label coming next to the text field is somehow not aligned with the second character of the label because of the border of the text field. I even set the border to 0 but it still keep a thin border. there is lso a problem when trying to vertically align checkboxes with labels (see attached image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwfMa.gif